# Destructuring fallback to prevent undefined error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, destructuring

I have a list of array I do this:

```
const { id } = myArray.find(
        (obj) => obj === true)
```

If the `id` is not present it will throw error. How to prevent error in the same time use destructuring? I want to keep the logic in one line.

Comment: In `undefined` case you can assign default value like `const { id = 10 } = { id: undefined }`. [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) Not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns `undefined` once there is no fulfillment for the condition:

> The value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, `undefined` is returned.

So probably you can use `||` operator to check if you have any value returned from `.find()` or you can replace with empty object `{}` instead on the right side of the operator.

Probably the option for one-liner is the following:

```js
const myArray = [
  { id: 12 },
  { id: 13 },
  { id: 14 }
];

const { id } = myArray.find(e => e.id === 17) || {};

console.log(id);
```

So you can destructure `id` property even if it returned `undefined` in this way.

Also if you need you can add default value to your destructuring statement based on the documentation which states for [Destructuring statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as follows:

> A variable can be assigned a default, in the case that the value unpacked from the object is `undefined`.

```js
const { id = 10 } = {};

console.log(id);
```

I hope this helps!